# PHP pass by ref is not effectively used inside body

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I have a function that takes in 2 parameters like so:

```
 public function setAssociatedGrants(array &$conversions, array $grants)
    {
        foreach ($conversions as $conversion) {
            foreach ($grants as $grant) {
                if ($conversion["transaction_history_id"] == $grant["external_id"]) {
                    $conversion["new_key"] = $grant["external_id"];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`$conversions` and `$grants` are both nested arrays. I need to modify the inner arrays of `$conversions`, but I am getting the warning `pass by ref is not effectively used inside body`, and when I return `$conversions` the new key isn't in there. I am expecting the output to have the new key in there. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to use `as &$conversion`, otherwise `$conversion` is a copy.

Comment: Why are you returning the array if you're passing it by reference?

Comment: Woops.. yeah I was returning it for debugging purposes. I've edited the code

Comment: I'm not going to bother answering this, since it's almost certainly a duplicate, but I can't find an original. Just change `as $conversion` to `as &$conversion`